# Exercise from Rotman: formal power series ring as inverse limit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit, $J = (x)$ an ideal of $A[x]$.

Thus we can consider the inverse system defined as $$\psi_{n,m}: A[x]/J^m \to A[x]/J^n$$ $$g(x) + J^m \to g(x) + J^n$$ $$\forall \ m\geq n$$ Then I have to prove that $$A[[x]] \cong \underleftarrow{\lim}A[x]/J^n$$

$A[[x]]$ is a cone over this inverse system via the projections $\pi_n : A[[x]] \to A[[x]]/ J^n \ \ \forall \ n$.

But how to prove that it is an universal cone ?  i.e. for every other cone $(M, \delta_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ over the inverse system there is an unique map $\lambda : M \to A[[x]]$ such that $$\pi_n \circ \lambda = \delta_n$$

Comment: May I ask which Rotman book is this from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would proceed as follows, identify $A[[x]]$ with the sub-ring of the infinite product $\prod_{n}A[X]/J^n$ of all elements $(p_n)_{n}$ such that $\psi_{n,m}(p_m)=p_n$ for all $n$ and $m$.

Then, you can define a map $\lambda:M\to \prod_{n}A[x]/J^n$ just sending $m\in M$ to $(\delta_n(m))_n$. Just verify that the image of this morphism is contained in $A[[x]]$. Uniqueness also follows easily because any morphism $M\to \prod_{n}A[x]/J^n$ is determined by the compositions $M\to \prod_{n}A[x]/J^n\to A[x]/J^n$.

Comment: Is the identification you mention the following: $a_0 + a_{1}X+a_{2}X^2+\dots \rightarrow (a_0,a_0 + a_{1}X,a_0 + a_{1}X + a_{2}X^2,\dots)$ ?In general, is the limit, in this case $A[[x]]$, always isomorphic to the set (equipped some binary operation(s), depending on the type of objects ) of all these special inifinite sequence you mentioned at the start?

Comment: Yes: that is the usual way to construct inverse limits in a lot of categories (e.g. sets, semigroups, topological spaces, rings, modules,...). You can prove that directly by verifying the universal property... Another way is to take an introductory book to, say, module theory (or category theory, topology, etc.) and the proof of the existence of inverse limits will probably be given by describing, in a way or another, the above construction.

Comment: Thanks @Simone!