# Formal Power Series and Inverse Limit

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a free group with generators $g_1,g_2,\dots$. Consider the group ring $RG$, where $R$ is a commutative ring.

Let $\epsilon: RG\to G$ be the augmentation mapping and let $I=\ker\epsilon$ be the augmentation ideal of $RG$.

To be precise, $\epsilon$ is the map $$\epsilon(\sum_{g\in G}a_gg)=\sum_{g\in G}a_g$$

Let $A=\lim_n RG/I^n$, the inverse limit. How do we describe $A$ as a formal power series?

I was told that $A$ is an algebra of formal power series on non-commuting variables ($g_1+1,g_2+1,\dots$?), but I am not sure how to prove it.

Thanks.

---

I read the question in [Exercise from Rotman: formal power series ring as inverse limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807474/exercise-from-rotman-formal-power-series-ring-as-inverse-limit), possibly the first step is to construct an inverse system, which is:

$\psi_{n,m}: RG/I^m\to RG/I^n$

$\alpha+I^m\mapsto \alpha+I^n$ for all $m\geq n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noncommutative power series is by definition

$$\mathbb C\langle\langle y_1,\ldots, y_n\rangle\rangle = \lim_N\ \mathbb C\langle y_1,\ldots, y_n\rangle/(y_1,\ldots, y_n)^N$$

There is a linear change-of-variables isomorphism $\mathbb C\langle y_1,\ldots, y_n\rangle \cong \mathbb C\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n\rangle$ sending $y_i = 1 - x_i$, so noncommutative power series is also equal to

$$"\ = \lim_N\ \mathbb C\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle/(1-x_1,\ldots,1-x_n)^N$$

You could also flip the sign on the $x_i$ if you wanted.

---

The map

$$\mathbb C \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n, x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}\rangle \ \ \to\ \ \lim_N\ \mathbb C\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle/(1-x_1,\ldots,1-x_n)^N$$

sending $x_i \mapsto x_i$ is well-defined because $x_i^{-1} = \frac1{1-(1-x_i)} = \sum (1-x_i)^k$ is convergent with respect to the limit.

The augmentation ideal is the preimage of $J = (1-x_1,\ldots, 1-x_n)$ of the formal power series ring, because $1 - x_i^{-1} = -x_i^{-1}(1-x_i)$. So the homomorphism extends to the completion,
$$\lim_N\, \mathbb C\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n,x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}\rangle/I^N \ \ \to\ \ \lim_N\ \mathbb C\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle/(1-x_1,\ldots,1-x_n)^N$$

To prove it's an isomorphism you just check the inverse is well-defined, but this is the easier direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask what is the condition for a homomorphism to extend to the completion?

I can understand your solution up till "is convergent with respect to the limit".

Comment: Let $A,B$ be filtered rings with filtrations denoted by $F^iA, F^iB$. Given a moprhism $A \to B$, the condition that the it preserve the filtration, i.e. $im(F^iA) \subset F^iB$, ensures that the map extends to the completion $\hat A \to \hat B$. In our case I started with a map $A \to \hat B$, but $\hat B$ is still filtered by $F^i$ so it's the same situation.

Comment: I said "convergent with respect to the limit" because there is this language about the filtrations making $A,B$ into topological rings, and the completion can also be constructed as the equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences as in topology.

Comment: @yoyostein The point is, when you are defining something as an infinite sum in a filtered ring, you need to justify why it is an element of the ring. For instance, $(1-x_i)^{-1} = \sum_k x_i^k$ would not be convergent in this ring, as we don't know $x_i^k \in F^kB$ or something similar. So the map would not extend to the localization at $1-x_i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For an element like $1-x_1x_2$ in the augmentation ideal, how do I see that it belongs to $(1-x_1,1-x_2,\dots,1-x_n)^N$ for some $N$?

Comment: Update: I think I got it, $(1-x_1)(1-x_2)-(1-x_1)-(1-x_2)=1-x_1x_2$.

Comment: @yoyo That's a good point, if a group $G$ has generators $g_i$ then the augmentation ideal of its group algebra is generated by the $1-g_i$. There is however a minus sign missing the way you have put this equation: the formula should be $(1-x_1)(1-x_2) = 1-x_1 - x_2 + x_1x_2 = (1-x_1) + (1-x_2) - (1-x_1x_2)$ or $1-x_1x_2 = (1-x_1) + (1-x_2)  - (1-x_1)(1-x_2)$.

Comment: By the way this formula shows up as the equation for the multiplicative formal group law as well. [formal group laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_group_law#Examples).

Comment: Regarding "then the augmentation ideal of its group algebra is generated by the $1−g_i$", how about the terms $1-g_i^{-1}$ with inverses of the generators?

Comment: @yoyostein Right, these are already in the ideal because of the other relation $-g_i^{-1}(1-g_i) = 1-g_i^{-1}$

Comment: I think I get it now. The augmentation ideal is generated by the $1-g_i$ as an algebra over $R$, not as a module over $R$ (my previous misunderstanding). Is that correct?

Comment: You had it right before - it's generated by the $(1-g_i)$ as an *ideal*, which is to say as an $RG$-module (ideal = submodule of regular module). As a (nonunital) algebra over $R$ i think it is not generated by the $1-g_i$, you need the $1-g_i^{-1}$ too. And as you expected, if it's being generated as a module only over $R$ then you need $1-g$ for all $g\in G$.