# $\varprojlim k[t]/(t^n)\simeq k[[t]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to show

> $\varprojlim k[t]/(t^n)\simeq k[[t]]$ where $k$ is a field.

This question is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/807474/668308) but the answer is identifying $k[[t]]$ and $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}k[t]/(t^n)$ which is how we construct the inverse limit. I want to show this by showing the universal property which is the original question in the same post.

> If $(M,\delta_n)$ is an inverse system such that $\psi_{n,m}\delta_m = \delta_n$ for $m\geq n$ then there is a unique morphism $\varphi: M\to k[[t]]$ such that $\pi_n\varphi = \delta_n$.

How can I get such $\varphi$?

Comment: How do you define $k[[t]]$? Usually, the inverse limit *is* the definition.

Comment: @KentaS Formal power series $k[[t]]:=\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_it^i|a_i\in k\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(M,\delta_n)$ be an inverse system, and let $m\in M$ be arbitrary. For each $n\ge 0$ let $a_n$ be the coefficient of $t^n$ in $\delta_{n+1}(m)\in k[t]/(t^{n+1})$. Then, we let $\varphi(m)=\sum_{n\ge 1}a_nt^n$. It is easily checked that this map $\varphi\colon M\to k[[t]]$ is in fact a $k$-homomorphism. Now for each $n$ we wish to check that $\pi_n\circ \varphi(m)=\delta_n(m)$, or equivalently, that for each $\ell<n$ the coefficient of $t^\ell$ of $\delta_n(m)$ matches the coefficient of $t^\ell$ of $\varphi(m)$.

By definition the coefficient of $t^\ell$ of $\varphi(m)$ is the coefficient of $t^\ell$ in $\delta_{\ell+1}(m)$. Now, equality simply follows from $\psi_{\ell+1,n}\delta_n=\delta_{\ell+1}$.

To prove uniqueness, suppose $\psi\colon M\to k[[t]]$ is another morphism satisfying the same property. Now, for each $n$ we have $\pi_n\circ \varphi=\delta_n=\pi_n\circ\psi$, so letting $\eta=\varphi-\psi$ we obtain $\pi_n\circ\eta=0$. If $\eta\ne0$ there would exist a $m\in M$ with $\eta(m)\ne0$. Let $\ell\ge 0$ be the least integer where the coefficient $a$ of $t^\ell$ of $\eta(m)$ will be nonzero. However then $\pi_{\ell+1}(\eta(m))=\pi_{\ell+1}(at^\ell+\cdots)=at^\ell=0\in k[t]/(t^{\ell+1})$, a contradiction.